# The POST method

Tags: php, database, laravel

I'm new to laravel and I want to submit a form which have some attachments plus some arrays but when I click submit button Laravel says:
The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.
some body help me please
----------
here is the page code

```
@extends('product.layout')

@section('content')`enter code here`

    <br><br><br>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 margin-tb">
            <div class="pull-left">
                <h2>Add new Product</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br><br><br>
        <div class="pull-right">
                <a class="btn btn-success" href="{{ route('product.index') }}">Back</a>
            </div>
    <form action="{{route('product.store')}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <strong>Product name :</strong>
                        <input type="text" name="product_name" calss="form-control" placeholder="Product">
                </div>
            </div>

                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <strong>Product Code :</strong>

                        <input type="text" name="product_code" calss="form-control" placeholder="Code">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <strong> Detials :</strong>

                            <textarea class="form-control" name="product_details" placeholder="Details"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <strong>Product image :</strong>
                            <input type="file" name="product_logo">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
        </div>
            </div>



    </form>



@endsection
```

---

here is the product controller

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\product;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB as FacadesDB;
use DB;


class ProductController extends Controller
{
    public   function index(){
       $products = product::all();
       return view('product.index' ,compact('products'));
    }

public function create(){
    return view('product.create');
}
    public function store(Request $request ){

        $data = array();
        $data['product_name'] = $request->product_name;
        $data['product_code'] = $request->product_code;
        $data['product_details'] = $request->product_details;

        $image = $request->file('product_logo');
 if ($image){
     $image_name = date('dmy_H_s');
     $ext = strtolower($image->getClientOriginalExtension());
     $image_full_name = $image_name.'.'.$ext;
     $upload_path = 'public/media/';
     $image_url = $upload_path.$image_full_name;
     $data['product_logo'] = $image_url;
     $success =$image->move($upload_path,$image_full_name);
     $data['product_logo'] =$image_url;
     $product =DB::table('products')->insert($data);

             }
        return redirect()-> route('product.index')
            ->with('success','Product Created Successfully');

    }
}
```

and also you can see

```
Route::get('store','ProductController@store')->name('product.store');
```

Comment: Your `store` route is a `GET` request: `Route::get('store', ...)`. Do you think that should maybe be `Route::post()`?

Answer (score 0):

change your route get to post. Route::post

Answer (score 0):

change:

```
Route::get('store','ProductController@store')->name('product.store');
```

to a post method:

```
Route::post('store','ProductController@store')->name('product.store');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your wrote `get` in your route but in form you wrote `post`
So you change your route like this.

```
Route::post('store','ProductController@store')->name('product.store');
```